# Agora.io generated token invalid ( C# / Angular )

Tags: c#, angular, agora.io

I'm trying to get an Angular component to join an Agora video call using a token generated using C#.

When using a specific UID instead of "0" (permit all) the generated token fails with this error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): AgoraRTCError CAN_NOT_GET_GATEWAY_SERVER: invalid token, authorized failed data: {"retry":false}

Token is generated using C# and the code from the Github Repo at https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/tree/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/csharp/src/AgoraIO

```
var token = new AgoraIO.Media.AccessToken(AGORA_APPID, AGORA_CERT, channelHash, userId);
```

where `AGORA_APPID` is the app id, `AGORA_CERT` the certificate, `channelHash` is a hash value for the channel, and `userId` is a guid.

Token is then retrieved by an Angular component, and used to join a channel, using the AgoraWebSDK-NG typescript SDK.

Using an unspecified UID (0 during creation, null during joining) works fine, so AppId, Cert, and channelHash are probably good.

Using a specified UID, be it numeric or alpha, leads to the invalid token error.

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I bothered, figured it out late at night. My bad for trusting my own input, i found that i used a different hash method for the channel name...

Comment: so whats a solution?

Comment: The solution was: Make sure that i use the same hash method... This was a problem with my own code, something i messed up.

Comment: Ahh okay i misunderstood that. Thanks

Comment: @Ulli: I currently am facing a similar issue. I use exactly same code base that they have in the github repo to generate my token, but its not working. Do you mind share your solution or snippet of code ? Thank you